# Interleave Scheme, cons contract violation

Tags: scheme, racket

I am new to writing scheme for a class. We were asked to write an interleave method, and here is what I have so far:

```
(define (Interleave L1 L2)
  (if (null? L1) L2)
      (if (null? L2) L1)
          (cons (car L1) (Interleave (L2) (cdr L1))))
```

I am trying to run it in DrRacket using (Interleave '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6)) 
My expected output should be (1 4 2 5 3 6), but instead I keep getting an error:

```
car: contract violation
  expected: pair?
  given: ()
```

And I have no idea how to fix it. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your `if` does not have *else* branch. You put *else* code as separate statement, thus it always executed.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention DrRacket I assume you have written it in some other editor and pasted the code in? DrRacket usually indent correctly. You can force it with `CTRL+i`. Here is your code with that done in DrRacket:

```
(define (Interleave L1 L2)
  (if (null? L1) L2)                          ; dead code
  (if (null? L2) L1)                          ; dead code
  (cons (car L1) (Interleave (L2) (cdr L1)))) ; always done
```

The last line always happen so your test if either are `null?` doesn't do anything. they evaluate to `L2` and `L2` but since it is not the tail expression. In order for you `if` to have an impact the rest of your code have to be in them. You can also use `cond` which prevents the need to nest `if` so that it looks more like `elseif` does on other languages.

Since your procedure does not have a base case it fails when `car` or `cdr` fails when the argument is the empty list.

PS: I notice that you check if `L2` is `null?` but on the last line you do `(L2)` which means you call it as if `L2` is a procedure like `cons` and `car`. That will not work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I had (L2) initially looking just like L2, but forgot to take out the parentheses before posting. That was just something I was trying to do to get it working. I am working on implementing your suggestions now.